Need help to identify an SSD Voltage regulator
I'm trying to get my data back from my dead SSD, I found a short on the voltage regulator that become very hot when putting the power but I can't identify the part and get the datasheet.
Here is a a picture from the component itself: 
Thanks you for your help!

Voltage regulator getting hot usually indicates a downstream short rather than a short inside the device.

As an ID question this is fine. But, it may be that the regulator is fine and some other component shorts the regulator output to GND.

What are all the stains from? Has this thing been in water?

I found a short on the voltage regulator where exactly? Between the 5V and ground? Did you have a chance to measure the voltage across the 5V output (pins 7-8-9 on the SATA signal connector) and ground (pins 10 or 12 or 4-5-6 on the SATA signal connector)?

It's an Onsemi NIS5135MN1TXG electronic fuse.


(Source: lcsc.com)

Thanks you very much !
